# Disabling gunicorn certificate validation

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

i'm creating an application with Flask and i'm using gunicorn as my application server. I enabled the verification of the client's certificate, and i would like to know if there is a way to disable the validation of client's certificate for a specific user or if there is a way to use two address:1 that uses https and another that uses http.

```
gunicorn configuration
import ssl


bind = "0.0.0.0:8080"
ca_certs = "certs/ca-crt.pem"
certfile = "certs/server-crt.pem"
keyfile = "certs/server-key.pem"
cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
worker_class = 'proto_worker.CustomSyncWorker'

from gunicorn.workers.sync import SyncWorker
import werkzeug.serving
import OpenSSL


class CustomSyncWorker(SyncWorker):
    def handle_request(self, listener, req, client, addr):
        cert = client.getpeercert()
        try:
            key = client.get_password()
        except:
            key = ''
        headers = dict(req.headers)
        #headers['CERT'] = dict(cert)
        headers['CERT'] = str(cert)+str(key)
        req.headers = list(headers.items())
        super(CustomSyncWorker, self).handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that render the certificate validation useless and compromise the whole sites security?

Comment: I have to create APIs that will be used by others applications. There is a side (the interface) that it will be used by this applications and they'll need to show a certificate, and another side (the configurations). I was asked to make this:if a specific user(like an admin) want to access the configuration side, he doesn't have to show a client certificate, keeping only the certificate server-side. For the configuration i have a login screen to determine if the user is an admin.